# Calculating jumping animation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, geometry

I'm trying to animate a jump using 3 variables: Jump distance, jump height and maybe jump "speed".

[Here is a working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottenmann/EhWAR/). However, I'd like the animated jump to be a perfect parabola.

```
var y = 300;
var x = 0;
var jh = 100;
var jw = 200;
var c = 0;

    var inter = setInterval(function () {
        c++;
        // if box reaches jump height it should fall down
        y = (c >= jh) ? y + 1 : y - 1;
        // if box reaches jump distance
        if (x == jw) clearInterval(inter);

        x++;

        $('.box').css({
            'top': y + 'px',
            'left': x + 'px'
        });

    }, 20);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually tell us enough. It might, but when you say "bow", do you mean that you want it to be a perfect semicircle? Because that's what you'd get, using your current numbers. Also, is this a jump animation? Is it an animation that you need to be able to use multiple times, or is it just something that only has to happen once, and will always happen at the same place, and speed and height?

Comment: Hey, yes i want to reuse it thats my main point and i dont think it is an semicircle it is more of an semi elliptical.

Atm i have hardcoded it so that the height gets subtracted lesser over time and when it reaches the "jumpheight" it goes the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking sine?  Assuming jh is "Jump height" and jw is "distance" without cleaning up the existing code you could do something like this:

```
var y = 300;
var x = 0;
var jh = 100;
var jw = 200;
var c = 0;
var speed = 3;

var inter = setInterval(function () {
    c++;
    y = getHeightAtX(x);
    if (x >= jw) clearInterval(inter);

    x+=speed;

    $('.box').css({
        'bottom': y + 'px',
        'left': x + 'px'
    });

}, 20);

function getHeightAtX(x) {
 return jh*Math.sin(x*Math.PI/jw)   
};
```

Comment: i have tried it and it didn't seem to work for me: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottenmann/EhWAR/2/) . But i bet this way is the right way to solve my problem.